# How to achieve conditional per-page javascript when all app javascript is compiled into one file?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Most modern frameworks like to include as much app JS in one file as possible to reduce server requests. This requires some kind of "check" for which page needs to activate what JS. Does jQuery support a structure like this or should I roll my own? Or is there a standard in the industry that has been adopted in terms of organizing/architecting this?

Currently I'm doing

```
$(document).ready(function(){ if $(body).hasClass('controler action') { ... } });
```

Example:

Is this a hack and is there a better way?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Only for lessons#search
    if (!$(body).hasClass('lessons search')) {
        return;
    }

    function close_style_filter_box() {
        $('#style_filter_box').slideUp();
    }

    $('#cond_style').focus(function(){ //make styles open when style input receives focus
        $('#style_filter_box').slideDown();
    });

    $('#close_style_filter_ctl').click(function(){ //make styles open when style input receives focus
        close_style_filter_box();
    });

    $('#with_level').select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1
    }); 
    $('#instructor_select').select2(); 
});
```

I suppose another way would be to always preface selectors with body classes like:

```
$('body.controller.action #style_filter_box').slideUp();
```

But this seems tedious...

Comment: This is a micro-optimization question at best. Let's look at the `why`. Common browsers can only perform 2 HTTPD requests simultaneously, per thread (across each open tabs/browser). If you're having 50 files that must be processed, and, perhaps each file has a small amount of data, it's highly unlikely that you're going to give your visitor performance issues, unless they have their own network problems. If you have 150 + files, then yes, that can become troublesome because the milliseconds will add up. You may be wasting time. Far more important are SPRITES.

Comment: Perhaps, but it has been the default in Ruby on Rails for several years, so it's actually hard to avoid. "The first feature of the pipeline is to concatenate assets, which can reduce the number of requests that a browser makes to render a web page. Web browsers are limited in the number of requests that they can make in parallel, so fewer requests can mean faster loading for your application.

Sprockets concatenates all JavaScript files into one master .js file and all CSS files into one master .css file."    http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: First approach is far simpler to manage than the second. On a side note, was reading recently that next gen browsers will up the simultaneous connections drastically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Paloma](https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma) gem. It provides a mechanism so you can:

- Choose what specific javascript code to run per page.
- Easily make ruby variables available to your javascript files.

You can read more about the theory and implementation of page-specific JavaScript in my article on [Rails and JavaScript](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html).